# Android app works fine on phone 7.0 and crashes on tablet running 7.1.2 on load

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, logcat, vuforia

I have an app built in Unity and Vuforia and it is running very nicely on my ZTE phone that is running Android 7.1.1.

However when I try to run it on my brand new Android tablet (just arrived from Amazon today) running 7.1.2 the app crashes almost immediately upon load.

I read through a few other threads but I may not be a good enough user yet to know what I am doing wrong...

I set the device to debug mode and ran Android Studio. Below is my logcat error result

```
    05-09 16:34:54.189 3531-3613/? E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
05-09 16:35:03.331 3531-3613/? E/AR: CameraDevice::getCameraCalibration(): Failed to get camera calibration because the camera is not initialized.
05-09 16:35:03.827 3531-3613/? E/Unity: Could not initialize the tracker.

    (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
05-09 16:35:05.032 8029-5080/? E/CdxFlvParser.c: <__CdxFlvParserProbe:4031>: [40;31mFlvProbe failed.[0m
05-09 16:35:05.032 8029-5080/? E/CdxAviParser: <__CdxAviParserProbe:1247>: [40;31mAviProbe failed.[0m
05-09 16:35:05.032 8029-5080/? E/CdxPmpParser: <PmpParserProbe:1127>: [40;31mIt is not pmp-2.0, and is not supported.[0m
05-09 16:35:05.051 8029-5085/? E/CdxFlvParser.c: <__CdxFlvParserProbe:4031>: [40;31mFlvProbe failed.[0m
05-09 16:35:05.051 8029-5085/? E/CdxAviParser: <__CdxAviParserProbe:1247>: [40;31mAviProbe failed.[0m
05-09 16:35:05.052 8029-5085/? E/CdxPmpParser: <PmpParserProbe:1127>: [40;31mIt is not pmp-2.0, and is not supported.[0m
05-09 16:35:05.070 8029-5090/? E/CdxFlvParser.c: <__CdxFlvParserProbe:4031>: [40;31mFlvProbe failed.[0m
05-09 16:35:05.070 8029-5090/? E/CdxAviParser: <__CdxAviParserProbe:1247>: [40;31mAviProbe failed.[0m
05-09 16:35:05.070 8029-5090/? E/CdxPmpParser: <PmpParserProbe:1127>: [40;31mIt is not pmp-2.0, and is not supported.[0m
05-09 16:35:06.328 3531-3613/? E/AR: VideoBackgroundConfig with screen size of zero received, skipping config step
05-09 16:35:15.210 3531-4863/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-20
    Process: com.FractalEncrypt.EVM, PID: 3531
    java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [Thread-20]
    Unity version     : 2017.3.1f1
    Device model      : F5CS LTD Fusion5_108
    Device fingerprint: Fusion5/Fusion5_108/Fusion5_108:7.1.2/N2G48B/20171222:user/release-keys

    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:902)
05-09 16:35:19.477 8838-8915/? E/AW PowerHAL: Error opening /sys/class/devfreq/sunxi-ddrfreq/dsm/scene: No such file or directory
05-09 16:35:24.010 8029-5081/? E/awplayer: <PlayerStop:852>: [40;31minvalid stop operation, player already in stopped status.[0m
05-09 16:35:24.014 8029-5081/? E/awplayer: <PlayerStop:852>: [40;31minvalid stop operation, player already in stopped status.[0m
05-09 16:35:24.018 8029-5086/? E/awplayer: <PlayerStop:852>: [40;31minvalid stop operation, player already in stopped status.[0m
05-09 16:35:24.020 8029-5086/? E/awplayer: <PlayerStop:852>: [40;31minvalid stop operation, player already in stopped status.[0m
05-09 16:35:24.024 8029-5091/? E/awplayer: <PlayerStop:852>: [40;31minvalid stop operation, player already in stopped status.[0m
05-09 16:35:24.026 8029-5091/? E/awplayer: <PlayerStop:852>: [40;31minvalid stop operation, player already in stopped status.[0m
05-09 16:35:31.533 9607-9607/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
05-09 16:35:31.534 9607-9607/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
05-09 16:35:32.699 9934-23574/? E/NetworkScheduler: Unrecognised action provided: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
05-09 16:35:33.165 11583-11583/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.t.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
05-09 16:35:33.253 9607-9607/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
05-09 16:35:33.328 9934-23574/? E/NetworkScheduler: Unrecognised action provided: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
05-09 16:35:34.355 6873-6932/? E/YouTube: Failed delayed event dispatch, no dispatchers.
05-09 16:35:34.783 6873-6928/? E/art: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0
05-09 16:35:41.217 7357-7357/? E/art: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0
05-09 16:35:48.132 9934-10879/? E/aghj: Phenotype API error. Event a <
      a: "LOCAL.com.google.android.agsa.QSB"
      b: 0
      e: ""
      f: ""
      g: 0
      h: 0
      i: ""
      j: 26
    >
    e: # bjyw@f5129a56
    , EventCode: 7 -- metadata{ service_id: 51 }
    aggc: 29505: No config packages for log source, or config package not registered
        at aghv.b(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):4)
        at aghj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):40)
        at aghj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):108)
        at oqt.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):40)
        at azva.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):2)
        at ovb.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):27)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at pbc.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626))
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
05-09 16:35:48.134 9934-10879/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=51, operation=GetExperimentTokensOperationCall
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=No config packages for log source, or config package not registered, resolution=null}]
        at aghj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):53)
        at aghj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):108)
        at oqt.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):40)
        at azva.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):2)
        at ovb.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):27)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at pbc.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626))
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
05-09 16:35:57.613 9934-10879/? E/aghj: Phenotype API error. Event a <
      a: "com.google.android.gms.devicedoctor"
      b: 208
      e: ""
      f: " com.google.android.gms.devicedoctor 208 7 1493864118 com.google.android.gms.devicedoctor 1493864118"
      g: 0
      h: 0
      i: "com.google.android.gms.devicedoctor"
      j: 1862
    >
    e: # bjyw@f5129982
    , EventCode: 5 -- metadata{ service_id: 51 }
    aggc: 29501: Stale snapshot (change count changed)
        at aghm.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):13)
        at aghl.b(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):1)
        at aghj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):40)
        at aghj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):108)
        at oqt.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):40)
        at azva.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):2)
        at ovb.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):27)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at pbc.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626))
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
05-09 16:35:57.620 9934-10879/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=51, operation=CommitToConfigurationOperationCall
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=Stale snapshot (change count changed), resolution=null}]
        at aghj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):53)
        at aghj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):108)
        at oqt.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):40)
        at azva.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):2)
        at ovb.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):27)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at pbc.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626))
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
05-09 16:36:03.370 10754-11039/? E/AsyncOpDispatcher: Unable to get current module info in ModuleManager created with non-module Context
05-09 16:36:05.768 9934-10880/? E/aghj: Phenotype API error. Event a <
      a: "LOCAL.com.google.android.agsa.QSB"
      b: 0
      e: ""
      f: ""
      g: 0
      h: 0
      i: ""
      j: 33
    >
    e: # bjyw@f5129a56
    , EventCode: 7 -- metadata{ service_id: 51 }
    aggc: 29505: No config packages for log source, or config package not registered
        at aghv.b(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):4)
        at aghj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):40)
        at aghj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):108)
        at oqt.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):40)
        at azva.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):2)
        at ovb.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):27)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at pbc.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626))
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
05-09 16:36:05.781 9934-10880/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=51, operation=GetExperimentTokensOperationCall
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=No config packages for log source, or config package not registered, resolution=null}]
        at aghj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):53)
        at aghj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):108)
        at oqt.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):40)
        at azva.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):2)
        at ovb.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):27)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at pbc.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626))
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
05-09 16:36:11.601 8838-8882/? E/BatteryStatsService: power: Platform does not even have one low power mode
05-09 16:36:11.612 8838-8882/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
05-09 16:36:11.620 8838-8882/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
05-09 16:36:11.623 8838-8875/? E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat (No such file or directory)
05-09 16:36:11.674 9607-9607/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] queryModemActivityInfo: Empty response
05-09 16:36:11.682 8838-8882/? E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat (No such file or directory)
05-09 16:36:11.687 8838-8882/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
05-09 16:36:16.397 9607-9607/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
05-09 16:36:19.658 9934-9431/? E/SeTransactionSyncTask: Error retrieving account
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current tap-and-pay account
        at alty.b(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):3)
        at alty.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):1)
        at amnv.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):28)
        at com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.gcmtask.TapAndPayGcmTaskChimeraService.b(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):1)
        at com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.gcmtask.TapAndPayGcmTaskChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):1)
        at com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.phenotype.PhenotypeCommitIntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):47)
        at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):2)
        at dbn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):8)
        at nam.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):9)
        at dbs.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):10)
        at dbp.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):9)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
05-09 16:36:36.482 10754-11039/? E/AsyncOpDispatcher: Unable to get current module info in ModuleManager created with non-module Context
05-09 16:36:42.161 9934-10144/? E/SeTransactionSyncTask: Error retrieving account
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current tap-and-pay account
        at alty.b(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):3)
        at alty.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):1)
        at amnv.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):28)
        at com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.gcmtask.TapAndPayGcmTaskChimeraService.b(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):1)
        at com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.gcmtask.TapAndPayGcmTaskChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):1)
        at com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.phenotype.PhenotypeCommitIntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):47)
        at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):2)
        at dbn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):8)
        at nam.a(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):9)
        at dbs.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):10)
        at dbp.run(:com.google.android.gms@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):9)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
05-09 16:36:50.320 9607-9607/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
05-09 16:36:50.320 9607-9607/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
05-09 16:36:51.097 9934-10845/? E/NetworkScheduler: Unrecognised action provided: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
05-09 16:36:51.479 11583-11583/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.t.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
05-09 16:36:51.606 9934-10845/? E/NetworkScheduler: Unrecognised action provided: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
05-09 16:36:52.322 10170-10170/? E/art: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0
05-09 16:37:02.519 9607-9607/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
05-09 16:37:06.827 12278-12414/? E/bt_h5: h5_timeout_handler
05-09 16:37:06.828 12278-12441/? E/bt_h5: retransmitting (1) pkts, retransfer count(0)
    0x0B
    0x20
    0x07
    0x01
    0x12
    0x00
    0x12
    0x00
    0x01
    0x00
05-09 16:38:07.072 8838-9262/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=11, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND] ]
05-09 16:38:40.569 8031-8955/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
05-09 16:39:12.397 8031-8955/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
05-09 16:42:11.851 12278-12414/? E/bt_h5: h5_timeout_handler
05-09 16:42:11.851 12278-12441/? E/bt_h5: retransmitting (1) pkts, retransfer count(0)
    0x18
    0x20
    0x00
05-09 16:43:09.689 8031-8955/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
05-09 16:43:14.494 8031-8955/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
```

Comment: a user on the unity forums solved a similar problem https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-crash-call-to-opengl-es-api-with-no-current-context-logged-once-per-thread.368261/

Comment: Thanks Chris! I will give this solution a try and report back. Most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem when try to install application with already installed application. Probably it was different packages with same SHA-1 fingerprint or contrary... Just uninstall your previous installed applications.